# Python C-Extension comparing capsules

Tags: python, python-c-api

Let's say I have two capsules returned from my C-extension that both point to the same address. How could I compare these two capsule objects within python to check if they both point to the same address?

I've tries just simply comparing them (using `==`) but that returns False even if they are the same.

Comment: can you post the C code you wrote? Also, this might help: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/newtypes.html#object-comparison